# Gmail api mvc 5 not getting authorize IIS

Tags: api, model-view-controller, gmail

im using gmail api in my mvc 5 project and it works fine on local (debug mode)

**Heres my code:**

`UserCredential credential1;
            var folder = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/App_Data/MyGoogleStorage");
            credential1 = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    new ClientSecrets
                    {
                        ClientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
                        ClientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                    },
                    //GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows for read-only access to the authenticated 
                    // user's account, but not other types of account access.
                    new[] { GmailService.Scope.GmailReadonly, GmailService.Scope.MailGoogleCom, GmailService.Scope.GmailModify },
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(folder)
                );`

**but when i publish it and try to run from iis i got:**

> [ System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Net.HttpListenerException: Access is denied at System.Net.HttpListener.AddAllPrefixes() at System.Net.HttpListener.Start() at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.LocalServerCodeReceiver.StartListener() at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.LocalServerCodeReceiver.d__8.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.d__8.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.d__4.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.d__1.MoveNext() --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification) at DataOtomasyon.Helpers.gmailApi.d__2.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\DataOtomasyon\DataOtomasyon\Helpers\gmailApi.cs:line 58 ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Net.HttpListenerException (0x80004005): Access is denied at System.Net.HttpListener.AddAllPrefixes() at System.Net.HttpListener.Start() at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.LocalServerCodeReceiver.StartListener() at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.LocalServerCodeReceiver.d__8.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.d__8.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.d__4.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.d__1.MoveNext()<--- ]

I checked permission to all available iis users and grant read/write permission to all of them i really confused and any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
 credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true),
                new PromptCodeReceiver()).Result;
```

This might have been asked quite a while ago but I ran into the same issue and what solved it was using [PromptCodeReceiver](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/Src/Support/Google.Apis.Auth/OAuth2/PromptCodeReceiver.cs) instead of not setting a code receiver parameter. It turns out that [GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/Src/Support/Google.Apis.Auth/OAuth2/GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.cs) uses LocalServerCodeReceiver by default when a code receiver is not defined.

Comment: 400. That’s an error.

Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

The redirect URI in the request, urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob, can only be used by a Client ID for native application. It is not allowed for the WEB client type. You can create a Client ID for native application at https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient

Learn more

Request Details
That’s all we know.

Comment: If you are currently using _Web Application_ as Application type in your created credentials, you can try making a new one with the type **Other** and update your ClientId and ClientSecret values accordingly to it.